# ImportError: No module named 'resource' on windows

Tags: python, resources

I am using resource module on Windows i.e. `import resource`.

But it generates an error (`ImportError: No module named 'resource'`)
The [reference link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html) says it is for UNIX only.
So what is an alternate functionality to use on Windows?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, There is no other alternative in the windows. But first you need the decide what to use for resource. such as for CPU speed only you can either use registry keys to set the process id limit